# How to set default values in angular if they aren't given from the other component

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, components

I am trying to set the variables to a default value if nothing is inputted from the component using the dialog. I am getting an error saying that it is still '' when the expected values (default values) should be applied. I currently have a template error dialog with a model that looks like:

```
export interface ErrorData {
   message: string;
   errorMessage: string;
   etc...
}
```

The component looks like this:

```
constructor(
  public dialogRef-----etc,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ErrorData,
) {
  const defaultData = {
     message: 'this is an error',
     errorMessage: '404httperror',
  }

  this.data = {
     ...defaultData,
     ...this.data
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data` could be `null | undefined` ??

Comment: This `...this.data` spread operator here is overriding your defaults. I'm presuming `data` param is coming in as an empty object

Comment: @Drenai What would be the best way to incorporate this? I would want the variables in the spread to take place if they came in empty from the other component, but only the variables that are empty.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach:

```js
this.data.message = this.data.message || defaultData.message;
// repeat for each variable
```

Cleverer approach, where there may be many values

```js
this.data = Object.entries(defaultData).reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => {
    return {
       ...acc,
       [key]: data[key] || value
    }
}, {...data})
```

Note, I didn't run this, so syntax may be a bit off

Comment: Thank you, I am new to the front end, but I am getting the error [string, string] is not assignable to type ErrorData. What is the best way to convert this?

Comment: Where is that error exactly. Maybe try something like `(data as any)[key] || value`

Comment: I apologize, it is right where this.data is assigned. Is it possible to convert the statement? Or convert this.data as it's being assigned?